# Is it bad practice to modify the schema to change all currencies in app from (15,2) to normal decimal column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app i have been storing currencies as

```
:decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

I realized that common practice for currencies is to store it as a normal decimal column so i want to make the switch.

Making a migration and looking for every currency column is kind of a tedious task.

Can i just modify the `schema.rb` file or is this bad practice?

Also if anyone can think of a better solution please let me know

Comment: " is kind of a tedious task" - is it, though? Is it more tedious than scanning through schema.rb? Only marginally so. So yes, create a migration (or several), don't change schema.rb

Comment: Are you already in production? If so changing the schema.rb will not have any impact. A migration on the other hand will update all of these columns appropriately

Comment: @engineersmnky: "will not have any impact" - it will with `rake db:schema:load` 

Comment: thanks for the advice guys, i'm going to make a migration then!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why would you even suggest that? Do you hate all of your production data?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there are currencies having 3 decimals, like `OMR`. `{"BHD"=>3, "JOD"=>3, "KWD"=>3, "OMR"=>3, "TND"=>3, "IQD"=>3, "LYD"=>3, "CLF"=>4, "BTC"=>8}`.

Comment: @mudasobwa oh yes the ever popular Omani Rial. I happen to have 50﷼  in my wallet right now :)

Comment: @engineersmnky don’t even try to fool me :) [DDG says](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=50%EF%B7%BC+to+USD&t=canonical&ia=currency) it’s Yemeni Real, not Omani.

Comment: @engineersmnky RTL unicode is hard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema is generated each time you add migration, and changing it only allow you to make changes locally, assuming you restore your DB from schema.rb. Create new migration, that will change your column. It also will change your schema file. Also consider to add schema.rb to gitignore.

Comment: Thanks, i currently use heroku, i thought that every time i pushed to production and ran 'rake db:migrate' it was using the schema.rb file. I will just make the migrations.